# Objects clipping after export character from blender to Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender, game-development

I'm learning unity/blender and today i found this funny glitch, but i don't know how to solve this

it's only happens when the animation triggers. In blender it look fine, everything follow the bones and look prety good so far, but when i export to unity this happen.

The hair is whats clipping.

the animation in blender

[image]

same animation but in Unity

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it was prety simple, all i have to do is export the hair separated from the character
and attach to character head in unity.

:B